# Adobe Flash Projector?

Tags: 14.04

Trying to get Adobe Flash Projector, but i'm having some trouble. Can't seem to figure out how to get it running, so I can run the game Realm of the Mad God in it to reduce lag. Please Help.

Please note, I am VERY new to Ubuntu, so i'm pretty much clueless.

Answer (score 1):

The Adobe Flash Projector for Linux is poor and doesn't build very easily or work in 14.04+.

The easiest solution is to install `wine`, download the Adobe Flash Projector for Windows, open it, and then run the SWF file within that.  (Run the projector executable after downloading it, then open the SWF you want to play.  If it needs internet connectivity, it might not work 100% as expected, though.)